# How to create routes for LAN IPs in Windows XP

Tags: windows, local-area-network, ip-routing, 3g

Hello i'm trying to use lan and 3g network at the same time on XP, as per previous questions i need to create routes for lan ip ranges. How can i do this

Answer (score 3):

Which "previous question" would that be?

I assume when you connect your 3G device, it automatically overrides your default gateway, which you can check by using the command line and typing:

`route print`

The one with 0.0.0.0 as the destination is your default route. You can leave this alone, and just add a static route to your LAN network, over your LAN interface. This will allow you to use the 3G device for internet traffic.
Route print should also show you the interface table:

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
 20 ...00 07 61 7d 69 c8 ...... Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network) #2
 11 ...00 05 1b 4b 61 04 ...... ADM851X USB To Fast Ethernet Adapter
  9 ...00 1e 4f b1 d4 69 ...... Intel(R) 82566DM Gigabit Network Connection
  1 ........................... Software Loopback Interface 1
 17 ...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0  isatap.NFM_LVT.local
 21 ...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0  Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
 27 ...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0  Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
===========================================================================
```

In this case, `9` is my LAN adapter.

So, to allow my network to use that interface for LAN traffic, I would use the following add command:

`route -p add 10.38.0.0 mask 255.255.0.0 10.38.0.1 IF 9`

You can use `route add /help` for further command line information.

[XP Route guide](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/route.mspx)