# Separate corporate and internet traffic using two network interface (no vpn)

Tags: windows, networking, routing

I'm trying to achieve all non-corporate traffic to be routed thru wlan card #1 and corporate traffic thru wlan card #2.

- Wlan #1 = a wlan card embedded in the laptop
- Wlan #2 = a usb wlan card, thus, in the evening I'd just plug out the wlan #2.
- Non-corporate network setting is:
  gateway = 192.168.1.1
  netmask = 255.255.255.0
- Corporate network setting is:
  gateway =192.168.3.x
  netmask = 255.255.255.224

gateway changes depends on the access point I'm attached to.

I've read the answers proposed to a similar question asked [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/92575/how-to-route-different-traffic-thru-different-network-interfaces-in-windows)

One of the answers is:

> For your setup, I think the syntax is:
>
> route add 10.183.0.0 mask 255.255.0.0 10.183.148.5

Which I'd tried but traceroute still shows the internet traffic goes through corporate gateway.

I'd tried this too:

> To make the 3g card the default gateway, remove the default route of the 11 interface :
>
> route delete 0.0.0.0 10.57.175.79

But, Windows 7 complains of: The route deletion failed: Element not found.

My current setup is as follows:

```
> ===========================================================================
Interface List
 35...f0 b4 29 3b ca 4f ......Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter #3
 34...f0 b4 29 3b ca 4e ......Xiaomi 802.11n USB Wireless Adapter
 27...0c 8b fd 18 ee b1 ......Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
 22...00 ff 4e fe e2 07 ......TAP-Windows Adapter V9
 21...02 40 18 d5 09 01 ......BlackBerry Virtual Private Network
 12...0c 8b fd 18 ee ad ......Intel(R) Wireless-N 7260
 11...5c f9 dd 65 5a 80 ......Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 20...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
 32...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
 15...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
 31...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #4
 37...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #8
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1     192.168.1.40     25
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    192.168.3.129    192.168.3.154     25
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      169.254.0.0      255.255.0.0         On-link    169.254.37.137    261
   169.254.37.137  255.255.255.255         On-link    169.254.37.137    261
  169.254.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    169.254.37.137    261
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.1.40    281
     192.168.1.40  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.40    281
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.40    281
      192.168.3.0  255.255.255.224    192.168.3.129    192.168.3.154     26
    192.168.3.128  255.255.255.224         On-link     192.168.3.154    281
    192.168.3.154  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.3.154    281
    192.168.3.159  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.3.154    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    169.254.37.137    261
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.3.154    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.1.40    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    169.254.37.137   9999
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.3.154    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.40    281
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
      192.168.3.0  255.255.255.224    192.168.3.129       1
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.4.1  Default
===========================================================================
```

Interface list 12 = Wlan #1
Interface list 34 = Wlan #2

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you have 2 default gateways.

On the adapter with your corporate network, assign a static ip address with the default gateway field blank.

On the other adapter, leave everything the same.

If your corporate network has more networks then the one then you will need to add a route for each one.

For example let's say your corporate network that your adapter is connected to is 10.1.1.0 with a mask of 255.255.255.0 but you also have 10.1.2.0/24 as part of your corprate network then your computer will need a route to it.
the route would look like:

route add 10.1.2.0 mask 255.255.255.0 10.1.1.1 
Assuming that your default gateway on the corp network is 10.1.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

You are deleting a default route with `route delete 0.0.0.0 10.57.175.79`, but your default gateway you want to delete is `192.168.3.129`. That is the reason Windows is showing you the error message.

You need to use `route delete 0.0.0.0 192.168.3.129` to delete the corporate default gateway.

If you get different default gateways when connecting to the corporate network, then you need to adjust the command accordingly.

You can also use Joe's method of configuring a static IP address. However, if your corporate network uses DHCP to allocate IP addresses, then your IP address might change, and a static IP address could cause address conflicts.

I would prefer deleting the default gateway to the corporate network router.